# How to fetch element in center of screen with js

Tags: javascript

anyone know how to select the element that is closest to the center on the screen? maybe I can use something like onscroll Event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // create a bunch of elements for demo
  for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  }

  // get middle of window coords
  const x = window.innerWidth / 2,
    y = window.innerHeight / 2


  // target middle element
  document.elementFromPoint(x, y).style.backgroundColor = 'red'
})
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure,

collect all the elements and get their coordinates.  Then calculate the distance to the center point.